# Что не нравится IDE PyCharm в коде?

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

Имеется такой код:

```
EMAIL = 'user@mail.ru'
user_name = 'Петя'
json_ = {
                'fields':
                    {
                        'EMAIL': [{"VALUE": EMAIL, 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}],
                        'ASSIGNED_BY_ID': 8
                    }
            }

if len(full_name := user_name.split()) == 2:
    LAST_NAME, NAME = full_name
    json_['fields']['NAME'] = NAME
    json_['fields']['LAST_NAME'] = LAST_NAME
else:
    json_['fields']['NAME'] = user_name

print(json_)
```

Если его запустить, то он прекрасно отрабатывает:

```
{'fields': {'EMAIL': [{'VALUE': 'user@mail.ru', 'VALUE_TYPE': 'WORK'}], 'ASSIGNED_BY_ID': 8, 'NAME': 'Петя'}}
```

Но, PyCharm, почему-то подсвечивает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И говорит, что там д/б **int**. Если поставить туда интовое значение, то подсветка исчезает.

**Почему так?**

UPD:
Странное поведение. Если в словарь **fields** добавить еще ключ с текстовым значением, то подсветка тоже исчезает...

Конечно тут ошибки нет, но все же интересно узнать почему так себя ведет IDE.

Comment: PyCharm 2021.2.3 (Community Edition) Build #PC-212.5457.59, built on October 19, 2021. В вашем исходном коде ничего не подсвечивает

Comment: У вас и открывающая скобка во внутреннем словаре тоже подсвечена. Интересно почему.

Comment: @АлексейР, действительно, видимо была проблема в версии. Обновил до последней версии IDE - все подсветки исчезли..

Comment: @CrazyElf скобка видимо из-за PEP8

Comment: @DWolf_19 А что там - скобку нельзя переносить на другую строку или что? )

Comment: @CrazyElf я думаю можно переносить, но она должна тогда быть на одном уровне с началом ключа `'fields'`. А тут весь словарь какой-то кособокий. После autopep8 вот так становится: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBBcQ.png